# ffmpeg UDP stream error (subtitles)

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, udp, subtitle

I have HTTP stream which I like to convert to UDP:

```
http://192.168.1.44:8001/1:0:1:1F8:1B:2C0:E080000:0:0:0:
```

The Video, Audio and Subtitle work perfectly If I try to open this stream in **VLC** n **Ubuntu**.
so far, so good

Here is otput of `FFPROBE`

```
    ffprobe -i http://192.168.1.44:8001/1:0:1:1F8:1B:2C0:E080000:0:0:0:
ffprobe version git-2017-01-22-f1214ad Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc
  libavutil      55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 63.100 / 57. 63.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 69.100 /  6. 69.100
  libavresample   3.  2.  0 /  3.  2.  0
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[mpeg2video @ 0xa56fde0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 2 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'ht tp://192.168.1.44:8001/1:0:1:1F8:1B:2C0:E080000:0:0:0:':                                                                                                         
  Duration: N/A, start: 35782.514200, bitrate: N/A                                                                                                                                         
  Program 501                                                                                                                                                                             
  Program 502                                                                                                                                                                             
  Program 503                                                                                                                                                                             
  Program 504                                                                                                                                                                             
    Stream #0:0[0x13b1]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc                           
    Stream #0:1[0x13b2]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s                                                                                             
    Stream #0:2[0x1541](srp): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:3[0x1542](slv): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:4[0x1543](hrv): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:5[0x1544](cze): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:6[0x1545](hun): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:7[0x1546](ron): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:8[0x1547](alb): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:9[0x1548](bul): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                               
    Stream #0:10[0x13b9](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)                                                                                                             
  Program 505                                                                                                                                                                             
  Program 506
  Program 507
  Program 508
  Program 509
  Program 510
  Program 511
  Program 515
  Program 516
  Program 517
  Program 518
  Program 519
  Program 520
  Program 521
Unsupported codec with id 94215 for input stream 10
```

So I decide to use **FFMPEG** to  stream to UDP, and filter out unwanted SUB's

Here is FFMPEG cmd

```
ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2048 \
    -i "http://192.168.1.44:8001/1:0:1:1F8:1B:2C0:E080000:0:0:0:" \
    -map 0:0 -vcodec copy \
    -map 0:1 -acodec copy \
    -map 0:2 -map 0:6 -scodec copy \
    -f mpegts udp://239.0.10.3:40000?pkt_size=1316
```

And the output is:

```
    Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://239.0.10.3:40000?pkt_size=1316':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2(srp): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:3(hun): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

And the resulting stream is DISASTER ... audio is choppy, video fall apart etc etc

If I try same thing WITHOUT sub's (map 2 and 6) the video and audio is crystal clear and stream work well

But I need this two sub's.

To narrow down the problem, if I try to capture incoming stream into file:

```
ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2048 \
-i "http://192.168.1.44:8001/1:0:1:1F8:1B:2C0:E080000:0:0:0:" \
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:6 \
-codec copy \
-y -f mpegts /tmp/tst.ts
```

The resulting file is playable, sound OK, video OK, subtitles OK.

Looks like problem is with OUTPUT to UDP ???

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you watch your udp output on a wireless connection?

Comment: Thank you for reply. No, i have very well built network environment. ETH0 is grabbing HTTP stream, ETH1 is broadcasting UDP stream on gigabit switch. I tried with CentOS, Ubuntu, replaced switch, eth cards .... same result. WITHOUT **dvb_subtitle** stream, everything work fine. If i map 0:2 or 0:6 or both 2&6, output stream is fall apart

Comment: Looks like an issue in ffmpeg; I'd say issue with mpegts muxer but then you say it works if you are writing to file. Can you grab about a 30 seconds of wireshark capture of both input and output streams (in single capture file) with the subtitles mapped in?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will try this later. For now, i was captured two files, one with **FFMPEG** and one with **MPLAYER --dumpstream**. Both file is playable. But when i try to UDP stream captured files with **FFMPEG** same thing, stream fall apart if subtitles are included in stream.